# Visual Studio Code Emmet not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using **VisualStudioCode 1.20**.1 Version. Emmet is inbuilt according to VSC website.But when i am trying on VSC IDE and using anchor tag and referring to class dropdown-toggle the class is not auto suggested or recognized by vsc.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

In your vscode user setting, add

> "emmet.includeLanguages": {
>           "javascript": "html"
>        }

That way you can use emmmet in your js files.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.

Comment: This [link] (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration) shows the configuration to enable mapping between the languages supported by Emmet and language of our choice. However I was not able to get suggestions from Emmet, so I had to add a duplicate entry for 'javascript' as suggested above by @tienl to get it working.

Comment: 4 years later, this still fixed it for me.

Answer (score 65):

in vs code user setting add these

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "razor": "html",
    "plaintext": "jade"
}
```

Comment: This code `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` works for me. When you accidentally type something (e.g. pa instead of p for paragraph tag) and you delete the letter "a" and press tab, without this code emmet won't work.

Comment: hey , its not working inside .html file script tag , can you help with this , with above code I'm getting emmet autosuggestions in js , vue and HTML file but not in between of strip tag ```<script> its not working inside this </script>```

Answer (score 34):

This following worked for me:

1. Open Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Open Settings (JSON)
3. Add to the end:

   ```json
   "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
   "files.associations": {
       "*html": "html", 
       "*njk": "html"
   },
   ```

Comment: thanks. this has worked to add mustache templates as html

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to add to the others posting about `emmet.includeLanguages`, you can also add `"vue": "html"`, so like:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { 
        "vue-html": "html",
        "vue": "html",
        "javascript": "html"
    }
```

Comment: this is what did it for me, `"vue-html"` on its own was not enough, added the `"vue"` entry as well and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

Emmet **does not work on js file by default**. To solve that problem you have to enable *emmet abbreviation* in the vscode's settings.
First, open settings.json from any directory:

```
vim ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

To be more specific, on windows, you need to go to File > Preferences > Settings > Type in "Launch" > click on "Edit in settings.json"

Now you have to declare in settings.json that you will use emmet at js files:
(Its very simple just copy and paste into code setting file the code **highligted**)

```
{
    /*here are your existing settings*/
    /*THE CODE BELOW*/
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html",
        "razor": "html",
        "plaintext": "jade"
    }
     /*^^^^THE CODE ABOVE^^^^*/
}
```

Now just save it. Not necessary restart vscode.

For more details see [that post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) at vscode official webite.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you need to include the language in your settings file.

With newer versions of VSCode, you can open up settings by selecting Code > Preferences > Settings and then search for "Emmet: Include Languages" and simply add your language there.

I just did this to get emmet working on my react code.
[image: I just did this to get emmet working on my react code.]

Answer (score 7):

Check the file extension icon, does it show up as html5 or **dj** (which stands for django)?

[image]

If it shows as dj, then you have the Django VSCode extension. You can do 2 things:

- Remove the Django extension
- Add `"django-html": "html"` to emmet.includeLanguages (as per this [issue](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django/issues/33)), so mine now looks like this:

```json
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "vue-html": "html",
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "django-html": "html",
  },
```

Comment: Thank you! : D Added the `django-html": "html`, without removing the django extension or anything else and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Something I ran into that was driving me crazy trying to figure out was that the setting `"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation"` will affect emmet working in your javascript files too.

To solve, remove it from your `settings.json` or set it to:
`"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always"`

Comment: Dear God ... this was basically me too. That setting was just not in my settings.json even though it appeared to be when I was using the VSCode UI to toggle my settings. So - once I opened the settings.json I saw it was missing, added it, restarted ... and FINALLY I get emmet intellisense stuff! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

find setting.json file and add this code
and save it and if you don't know how to do it then watch this video
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUuP_hriEc4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUuP_hriEc4%60)

> "files.associations": {"*html":"html"},
> "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true

`

Answer (score 1):

With *aspnetcorerazor* and *razor* language selection add the below code in your `setting.json` file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "aspnetcorerazor" : "html", "razor" : "html" }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in HTML files because another extension (for Django, a Python web framework) was overriding .HTML file types without a way to turn it off. I removed the extension, restarted VSCode, and now it's working again.

Comment: simply adding `"django-html": "html"` to the user settings in VSCode -as @Ben Butterworth suggested- worked for me

Comment: removing a extension is not a solution because of extensions useful in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

In your setting.json file add this line `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,`. Then ! and tab will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VS Code **settings** -> Search `Emmet` -> In section **Emmet:Include Languages**, add `{item, value}`

`{javascript :javascriptreact}`

[image: picture here]

Answer (score 0):

Tried all above , didn't work.

Updated my VScode by reinstalling it from [here](https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/supporting/howtoupdate/) and everything works like a charm now.

Comment: You may have had the same issue I did https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432809/4223679

Comment: I tried everything , including your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall the extension related to HTML or CSS
And it work for me nicely

Comment: what if we want to use that extension?
please avoid writing a solution if it is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

`"editor.defaultFormatter": "VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode"`

Answer (score 0):

for me emmet auto-fill stopped to work on single html page ; turnout it was bcz i  used "<" twice not on a tag ( like withen the text)  ,
remove them or but \ before them or use them inside   (prism cdn is recomended then) will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and realized that the following setting wasn't checked.  When I checked the box, I went back to a test HTML file and used "!" to bring up the boilerplate, and this time it worked.

"Emmet: Use inline Completions"

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Start your VS Code. Click on the Settings or press **Ctrl+,** to open the VS Code Settings.

Step 2: Click on the **Extensions** tab on the left side of the settings. Click on HTML.

Step 3: Click on the **Edit in settings:json** hyperlink to edit the settings in JSON format.

Step 4: Inside the curly braces, enter the following code under the already written JSON code:

```
“emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab”:true,
“files.associations”: {“*html”:“html”},
“emmet.useInlineCompletions”:true
```

Step 5: Save the file. Now if you try to apply Emmet in your code, it will work smoothly!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to uninstall your VS code and Node.js by going into control panel → program & features.
2. After the uninstall is copmlete, go to `C:\Users\your_user_name_folder`.
3. After reaching there, delete the `.vscode` folder.
4. Go to `AppData\Roaming\Code` (delete this `Code` folder).
5. Go to `C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Local\Programs` and delete the Microsoft VS code folder.
6. Now go to `C:\Users\rajat\AppData\Local` and delete the `npm_cache` folder.
7. Now reinstall Node.js and VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is occurring due to any Django extension then simply adding
"django-html":"html" in "Emmet: Include Languages" in the settings will solve the problem.
[image: Like this]